# Testbench output unexpected (always stx and red line)

Tags: logic, verilog, test-bench

I want to try to make a functional implementation of a 16x1 Multiplexer. Everything seems OK, but when I test my project on testbench, output `m` is a red line and always writes stx. I need known results instead stx.

2x1 Multiplexer

```
module mux_2x1(y,d0,d1,s);

input d0,d1,s;
output y;
wire t0,t1;

and(t0,d0,~s);
and(t1,d1,s);
or(y,t1,t2);

endmodule
```

4x1 Multiplexer

```
module mux_4x1(y,d0,d1,d2,d3,s0,s1);

input d0,d1,d2,d3,s0,s1;
output y;
wire t0,t1;

mux_2x1 m1(t0,d0,d1,s0);
mux_2x1 m2(t1,d2,d3,s0);

mux_2x1 m3(y,t0,t1,s1);

endmodule
```

8x1 Multiplexer

```
module mux_8x1(y,d,s0,s1,s2);

input [0:7]d;
input s0,s1,s2;
output y;

wire [0:5]t;

mux_2x1 m1(t[0],d[0],d[1],s0);
mux_2x1 m2(t[1],d[2],d[3],s0);
mux_2x1 m3(t[2],d[4],d[5],s0);
mux_2x1 m4(t[3],d[6],d[7],s0);

mux_2x1 m5(t[4],t[0],t[1],s1);
mux_2x1 m6(t[5],t[2],t[3],s1);

mux_2x1 m7(y,t[4],t[5],s2);

endmodule
```

16x1 Multiplexer

```
module mux_16x1(y,d,s0,s1,s2,s3);

input [0:15]d;
input s0,s1,s2,s3;
output y;

wire [0:3]t;

mux_8x1 m1(t[0],d,s1,s2,s3);

mux_4x1 m2(t[1],d[8],d[9],d[10],d[11],s2,s3);
mux_4x1 m3(t[2],d[12],d[13],d[14],d[15],s2,s3);

mux_2x1 m4(t[3],t[1],t[2],s1);

mux_2x1 m5(y,t[0],t[3],s0);

endmodule
```

Verilog code, function implementation

```
module mux_16x1_imp(m,a,b,c,d);

input a,b,c,d;
output m;

//module mux_16x1(y,d,s0,s1,s2,s3);
mux_16x1 m1(m,{1'b0,1'b0,1'b1,1'b1,1'b0,1'b1,1'b0,1'b1,1'b1,1'b1,1'b1,1'b1,1'b0,1'b0,1'b0,1'b0},a,b,c,d);

endmodule
```

Here is my testbench code

```
module mux_16x1_imp_test();

reg a,b,c,d;
wire m;

mux_16x1_imp TestBench(m,a,b,c,d);

initial begin

a=1'b0; b=1'b0; c=1'b0; d=1'b0; #100    
a=1'b0; b=1'b0; c=1'b0; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b0; c=1'b1; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b0; c=1'b1; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b1; c=1'b0; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b1; c=1'b0; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b1; c=1'b1; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b0; b=1'b1; c=1'b1; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b0; c=1'b0; d=1'b0; #100    
a=1'b1; b=1'b0; c=1'b0; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b0; c=1'b1; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b0; c=1'b1; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b1; c=1'b0; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b1; c=1'b0; d=1'b1; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b1; c=1'b1; d=1'b0; #100
a=1'b1; b=1'b1; c=1'b1; d=1'b1; 

end

endmodule
```

Simulation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got compile warnings on 2 different simulators, and they pointed me to these 2 lines of code.

In `mux_2x1`, you used the undeclared `t2` instead of `t0`. Change:

```
or(y,t1,t2);
```

to:

```
or(y,t1,t0);
```

In `mux_16x1`, change:

```
mux_8x1 m1(t[0],d,s1,s2,s3);
```

to:

```
mux_8x1 m1(t[0],d[0:7],s1,s2,s3);
```

These changes fix the warnings and get rid of the x's.

If you didn't get any warnings, you could try your code on multiple simulators on **edaplayground**.